# Java: share object reference without passing as parameter

Tags: java, factory

I have an ObjectFactory and a specialized case of implementation of that factory. I can't change the interface, that has 0 argument.
In one of the implementation I have to read a file and load some data. To pass the filename I can use the system properties because all I need to share is a string.
But in the other implementation I must start not from a file but from a memory structure. How can I do to pass the object (then I think the object reference) to the factory? Other methods? No way I serialize the object on a file and after I read it again because what I want to avoid is right the I/O footprint.
Thanks

OK, more informations:

This is the interface and the abstract factory I have to implement

```
public abstract interface A
{
  public abstract Set<Foo> getFoo();
  public abstract Set<Bar> getBar();
}


//this is otherpackage.AFactory
public abstract class AFactory
{
    public static AccessFactory newInstance()
    {
        return a new built instance of the factory
    }

    public abstract A newA();
}
```

This is my implementation with my problem:

```
public class AFactory extends otherpackage.AFactory
{
    @Override
    public Access newA()
    {
        return new AA();
    }
}


public class AA implements A
{   
    protected AA()
    {
        this.objectReferenceIWantToSaveHere = I retrieve from the shared memory zone;
        use the object
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to do something like this:

```
B b = something I built before
save b in a shared memory zone or something like that
otherpackage.AFactory f = mypackage.AccessFactory.newInstance();
A a = f.newA();
```

And inside `the f.newA()` call I'd like to access to the b object

Comment: Please post your code. I can't follow what you're asking. You might pass the reference to the factory constructor.

Comment: Ok, added an example. You should understand I can't simply pass the reference because I have to implement an interface.

Comment: You could add an interface which specifies a `setB(B)`, then you could pass the reference there. Or, you might use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use a constructor?

```
interface ObjectFactory { Object create(); }

class SpecialFactory implements ObjectFactory {
    private final Object data;
    public SpecialFactory(Object data) { this.data = data; }
    @Override public Object create() { return somethingThatUsesData; }
}
```

Comment: No, I can't change the interface that is implemented so I can't use a constructor.

Comment: @user2714602 That is unclear - You can implement an interface and add whatever constructor you like...

Comment: Look at my example. I can't simply implement the interface and add a constructor. It's because to create an instance I have to call a static factory method. And I can't change that prototype.

Comment: Is the `B` object that you want to pass to the new `A`s always the same? Or is it different for each `A` object?

Comment: The second one, It is created at runtime from data got from the net.

Comment: Ok but once you have started your application, will it change every time you create a new `A`?

Comment: If the returned value is always different, the corresponding logic should probably be in the factory. If it is always the same for a given "session", you could use a singleton. However from a design perspective, it would be better to allow some form of dependency injection such as what I proposed in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ass assylias proposes, you can pass the reference to the constructor. Or if you know where to find the reference, you could just ask for it before you use it? E.g. `data = dataBank.giveMeTheData()`

Answer (score 0):

Agree it would help to get some more context around what you are doing... but could you use a shared static class in which your calling code places info into the static class, and your interface implementation references this same static class to obtain either the object and/or instructions?

So here's a client class. It has the entry point..and wants to pass an object to the interface implementer but it can't pass it directly...So it set's object it wants to pass in the MyStaticHelper.SetSharedObject method.

```
public class Client {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String mySharedObject = "Couldbeanyobject, not just string";

    // Set your shared object in static class
    MyStaticHelper.SetSharedObject(mySharedObject);

    InterferfaceImplementer myInterfaceImplementer = new InterferfaceImplementer();
    // 
    myInterfaceImplementer.RunMyMethod();


}
```

Here is the code for the static helper...

```
public class MyStaticHelper {
private static Object _insructionsObject;


public static void  SetSharedObject(Object anObject)
{
    _insructionsObject = anObject;
}

public static Object GetSharedObject()
{
    return _insructionsObject;
}
```

}

and finally the the class that you call that uses the static helper to get the same object.

```
public class InterferfaceImplementer {

// no objects
public void RunMyMethod()
{
    System.out.println(MyStaticHelper.GetSharedObject());
}
```

}

Again this works in a very simple scenario and wouldn't stand up if more than one implementer needs to be called simultaneously as this solution would only allow one obj to be in the static helper class.